# Solr Multivalued date range from two separate field as sub entity

Tags: solr, date-range, multivalue

I am a Apache Solr beginner.
My data-config.xml contains this code

```
<entity name="event">                        
<field column="event_id" name="id" />
...
<entity name="request_history" query="select request_date, request_expiry_date from request_history where id=event.id">
   <field column="request_date" name="start_date" />
   <field column="request_expiry_date" name="expire_date" />
</entity>
```

AND following is what in shcema.xml file against those fields

```
<field name="start_date" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="expire_date" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

So, for a single event, there can be multiple requests hence multiple "start_date" and "expire_date". Now I need to find all requests within a date range and all requests not within a given date range, but not getting any way.

Comment: fq=start_date:[NOW TO *] AND expire_date:[* TO NOW] would filter the results. However, is the issue with matching the end date with the start date ???

Comment: yes @Jayendra, thats the main problem actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a very easy way to solve the problem, alhamdulillah. Its a simple query pattern-

```
-(start_date: [2013-07-01T0:00:00Z TO 2013-07-18T0:00:00Z] AND end_date: [2013-07-01T0:00:00Z TO 2013-07-18T0:00:00Z])
```

This do what I need actually.

Answer (score 1):

Index the start date and expiry as single multivalued fields as per the event e.g. `event_date`. Rather than clubbing them into just two fields.
So that each event would have a entry for start date and expiry date combined and the `fq=start_date:[NOW TO *] AND expire_date:[* TO NOW]` query would work fine for you.
Make the field dynamic so that you don't need to configure.

Comment: Here request dates are proposed organizing date of  that event in. So i have no initial event date here.

Comment: you can maintain the event and use Solr partial updates to insert the dates as and when the event is created.